# All data points are not appearing in a line chart made using chart.js

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I am using Django 2.0 for back-end development of a BPO website. In that one, I am trying to show one accounting information (trail balance) of an organisation in a table and two separate line chart for credit and debit accounts.I am using Chart.js for plotting the line chart. The corresponding functions in view.py file of django are:

```
#this preprocess function is used to find out the credit and debit accounts

def preprocess(a):
    label1 = []
    label2 = []
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if int(a[i,1])!=0:
            label1.append(a[i,0])
            arr1.append(int(a[i,1]))
        else:
            label2.append(a[i,0])
            arr2.append(int(a[i,2]))
    return label1,label2,list(arr1),list(arr2)

@login_required
def Acc_Info(request):
    obj = request.user
    if(request.method=='GET'):
        obj1 = Company.objects.get(username=obj)
        dt = int(datetime.date.today().year)
        obj2 = AccountingInfo.objects.filter(company_code=obj1,date=dt)
        if obj2.exists():
            obj2 = AccountingInfo.objects.get(company_code=obj1,date=dt)
            path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/'+str(obj2.info)
            # names = ['Name of Account','Credit','Debit']
            data = pd.read_csv(path)
            data = np.array(data)
            # dr = list(data[:,1])
            # cr = list(data[:,2])
            label1,label2,dr,cr = preprocess(data)
            print("\n\ncr = ",cr)
            print("\n\ndr = ",dr)
            Debit_sum = data[:,1].sum(dtype=np.float64)
            Credit_sum = data[:,2].sum(dtype=np.float64)
            return render(request,'Acc_Info.html',{'f':True,'lc':len(cr),'lr':len(dr),'label1':label1,'label2':label2,'cr':cr,'dr':dr,'year':datetime.date.today().year,'data':data,'Suspense':Credit_sum-Debit_sum,'Credit_sum':Credit_sum,'Debit_sum':Debit_sum})
        else:
            return render(request,'Acc_Info.html',{'f':False,'year':dt})
    else:
        obj1 = Company.objects.get(username=obj)
        dt = request.POST['year']
        obj2 = AccountingInfo.objects.filter(company_code=obj1,date=dt)
        if obj2.exists():
            obj2 = AccountingInfo.objects.get(company_code=obj1,date=dt)
            path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/'+str(obj2.info)
            data = pd.read_csv(path)
            data = np.array(data)
            label1,label2,dr,cr = preprocess(data)
            print("\n\ncr = ",cr)
            print("\n\ndr = ",dr)
            Credit_sum = data[:,2].sum(dtype=np.float64)
            Debit_sum = data[:,1].sum(dtype=np.float64)
            return render(request,'Acc_Info.html',{'f':True,'lc':len(cr),'lr':len(dr),'label1':label1,'label2':label2,'cr':cr,'dr':dr,'year':dt,'data':data,'Suspense':Credit_sum-Debit_sum,'Credit_sum':Credit_sum,'Debit_sum':Debit_sum})
        else:
            return render(request,'Acc_Info.html',{'f':False,'year':dt})
    return redirect('/HRO/log_in/')
```

My HTML file is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-oSgtFCCmHWRPQ/JmR4OoZ3Xke1Pw4v50uh6pLcu+fIc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <title>
  Accounting Information
 </title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="text-center">
 <h2>Select Year for Checking the particular Account Information of that year</h2>
</div><br><br>
 <div class="text-center">
 <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label>Year: </label>
  <select id="year" name="year"></select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form><br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var start = 2000;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "";
for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
</script>
<div class="container">
 <h2>Accounting Information for the Year: {{ year }}</h2>
 {% if f %}
<table class="table table-hover table-stripe">
 <thead><tr>
  <th>NAME OF ACCOUNT</th>
    <th>DEBIT</th>
<th>CREDIT</th>
 </tr>

 </thead>
<tbody>
 {% for value in data %}
 <tr>
{% for any in value %}
<td>{{ any }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
 <tr>
<td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
<td>{{ Dredit_sum }}</td>
<td>{{ Crebit_sum }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
<label>Suspense Account: {{ Suspense }}</label>
</div>

<canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="400" class="col-md-4 offset-md-10"></canvas>
<canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400" class="col-md-4 offset-md-10"></canvas>
</body>
{% else %}
<h1>It Seems you have not uploaded Account Information for the chosen year</h1><br>
{% endif %}
<script type="text/javascript">
//if({{ f }})
//{
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext('2d');
 var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');

 // var backgroundColor1 = []
 // var backgroundColor2 = []
 // var border1 = []
 // var border2 = []

 // for(var i=0;i<{{ ld }};i++)
 // {
 //  backgroundColor1.push('rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)');
 //  border1.push('rgba(255,99,132,1)');
 // }
 // for(var i=0;i<{{ lc }};i++)
 // {
 //  backgroundColor2.push('rgba(132, 99, 255, 0.5)');
 //  border2.push('rgba(132,99,255,1)');
 // }
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: {
         datasets: [{
             label: 'Debit Accounts',
             data: {{ dr }},
             borderWidth: 1
         }]
     },
     options: {
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:true
                 }
             }]
         },
         responsive: false
     }
 });
 var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
     type: 'line',
     data: {
         datasets: [{
             label: 'Credit Accounts',
             data: {{ cr }},
             borderWidth: 1
         }]
     },
     options: {
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:true
                 }
             }]
         },
         responsive: false
     }
 });
//}
</script>
</html>
```

I have 2 questions:
1. Why is this plotting only first two data points
2. How to set a default colour in Chart.js charts, because the 'fillColor' method is not supported in this Chart.js version

The screen is appearing like this:
[The accounting info in table( it is appearing properly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvNHd.png)

The chart are as follows:
[The line charts( Only two points are appearing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plVu8.png)

P.S. It will be very helpful if I get some prompt answer because I have a project to submit. Thank you in advance :).

Comment: What version of Chart are you using? Versions 1 and 2 have significant differences. And what exactly does the chart data structure look like when you set up the graph?

Comment: I am using 2.7, the chart data structure is a list of integrs ( it is shown in the code as {{ cr }} and {{ dr }}

Comment: No I mean *exactly* what does it look like? Have you tried dumping it to the console with `console.dir()` to verify that it's got the content you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is getting the expected data values. But only two points are being plotted.

Comment: Well if you don't post the data in your question it's going to be quite difficult to figure out what's going on. There's no "only the first two points" mode in Chart.js, so there's something wrong with the data you're passing it.

Comment: When I am passing the lists 'cr' and 'dr'  to the html file, I am writing their contents to the console, the values are: {{ cr }} = [20000,2000], {{ dr }} = [19000,20000,10000,1000]. This is the expected value. When I am plotting them, the plot is appearing as given in the second picture that I have attached. I have also attached the picture of the table of accounting info, just check it once.